# How do i require user authentication to view dashboard page

Tags: php

On my index page i have my login form for users, then it goes to login.php to handle the login script, from there the users are redirected to dashboardd.php. But i want it to to be so that they have to be logged in to access this page, and not just type in the URL.

Index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<?php
  if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
    echo '<ul style="padding:0; color:red;">';
    foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
      echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Alec Grogan</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="login.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uname" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pword" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;
    // configuration
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "alecgrogan";
    $dbuser     = "root";
    $dbpass     = "";
    // database connection
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    // new data
    $user = $_POST['uname'];
    $password = $_POST['pword'];
    if($user == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Username';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Password';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    // query
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= :hjhjhjh AND password= :asas");
    $result->bindParam(':hjhjhjh', $user);
    $result->bindParam(':asas', $password);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if($rows > 0) {
    header("location: dashboard.php");
    }
    else{
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

dashboard.php

```
<?php
    echo "string";
?>
```

Comment: if login succesfull set a $_SESSION['myvar'] as what you want and the use it on if on dashboard.php (after starting the sessions)

Answer (score 2):

Make a `$_SESSION` e.g. `$_SESSION['logged_in']` and fill it with data or set it to true

```
$username = $_POST['username']; //don't forget to sanitize $_POST values
$userID = (int)$_POST['userID'];

$_SESSION['logged_in'] = array('username' => $username, 'id' => $userID);
OR
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
```

And then check on the dashboard

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    header('Location:index.php');
}
```

Now if it does not exists, it will return the user to index.php. Don't forget to use `session_start()` at the top of every page where you want to call the `$_SESSION` variables.

You can set an `array()` in a `$_SESSION`, so this is ideal for storing user info. **Do not** store user passwords in a `$_SESSION` tho.

Comment: I am getting this error! I added this at the top of login.php right under session_start(); $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;. And then on dashboard.php i added <?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    header('Location:/alecgrogan/index.php');
 echo "string";
?>

Comment: this is the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in Z:\xampp\htdocs\alecgrogan\dashboard.php on line 5

Comment: @AlecRobertGrogan, you have to check if the login that was entered is correct, and then set the `$_SESSION` to true. And you are missing a closing bracket! after `header('Location:/alecgrogan/index.php');` close it! with a `}`

Comment: I am so sorry i still do not understand what you are saying i put this at the end of login.php $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;, and then on dashboard.php i put session_Start(); then if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    header('Location:index.php');
}, and it still did not work i could view the page without being logged in

Comment: @AlecRobertGrogan Is that after you have logged in? Because the session stays true for as long as the browser is opened, or when the session is destroyed. You need to identify the user, if that was correct set session, now session is set until you close the browser comepletely, or when you unset the session using: `unset($_SESSION['logged_in']`. (this should be in you logout.php file (with `session_start()` at the top).